# get MongoDB results as objects instead of array

Tags: json, mongodb, object, find

I'm new to MongoDB, and I'm trying to get results in a different way.

if I execute the query db.collection.find().toArray() I get something like:

```
[
  {
    "_id":"34234...",
    "first":"Mark",
    "last":"Marker"
  },
  {
    "_id": "34235...",
    "first":"Adam",
    "last":"Smith"
  }
]
```

is there an api that lets you to receive the results as the following?:

```
{
 "results" : {

  "34234..." :{
    "_id":"34234...",
    "first":"Mark",
    "last":"Marker"
  },
  "4235..." :{
    "_id": "34235...",
    "first":"Adam",
    "last":"Smith"
  }

 }
```

Or I need to get the results array and iterate every single object and build my response? (I would like to avoid the single cursor iteration)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a native API function for that. `cursor.toArray()` goes through each item in the cursor begin with, so I wouldn't worry too much about that. We can just skip the `toArray()` and do our own iteration:

```
var obj = {}
db.collection.find().each(function(item){
  obj[item._id] = item;
});
```

I don't think that would really be any slower.

Comment: Ok I wanted to avoid this solution because my collections are on another server, so I suppose the "each()" function would be a request to the server( am I wrong?) If there is no API and I am not wrong about the previous thought, I think the solution is to get the results array and iterate it by (e.g.) NodeJS building my response.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have to get the data off the server one way or another, right? This solution doesn't do any iteration or access that `toArray` wouldn't be doing anyway (it consumes the cursor just like `each` does). Iterating through the result of `toArray()` is a bit less efficient, since it has to iterate through the cursor and then iterate through the array.