# Is there a native way to get MongoDB results as object instead of array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Checked couple of old similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456863/get-mongodb-results-as-objects-instead-of-array) but no luck in finding the right answers.

I have a mongo query that uses await/async to fetch results from the database, So the code looks like this :

```
(async () => {
  //get connection object
  const db = await getDatabaseConnection("admindb");

   //get user data object
  const configResponse = await db.collection("config").find({}).toArray();
  
  //prints results
  console.log("Successfully Fetched Configuration", configResponse);
})();
```

The above code works fine, just that it returns me an array of elements since I have used the `.toArray()` method.

Sample Result:

```
[
  {
    _id: "6028d30db7ea89f74df013d9",
    tokenize: false,
    configurations: { theme: {} }
  }
]
```

Is there a **NATIVE WAY** (not looking forEach responses) to get result as an object since I will always have only one document returned. I have multiple queries that returns only one document, Hence accessing using the 0th index everytime did not seem the right way.

Comment: A look into the documentation usually helps. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking if the **findOne()** will help you.

Check this out [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/findOne/)

```
await db.collection("config").findOne({});
```

Here are some [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#examples)